# Why do I get a blank space returned as last item in array from split

Tags: javascript, split

I want to be able to convert file contents from both unix and windows systems into an array.

So I use the regex /\r\n|\n/ to split on "\r\n" and also "\n".  Code:

```
const contents1 = 'line1\r\nline2\r\n';
const contents2 = 'line1\nline2\n';
const lines1 = contents1.split(/\r\n|\n/);
const lines2 = contents2.split(/\r\n|\n/);
console.log(lines1);
console.log(lines2);
```

I am reading the regex to mean split on either "\r\n" or "\n".

But when I run this code I get two arrays like this:

```
["line1", "line2", ""]

["line1", "line2", ""]
```

Why the blank line as last member of the array?

Can I change the regex to fix this issue?

Comment: It will try to split wherever it finds a match, so it will split on the last one and generate an empty string at the end.  Just trim trailing newlines (contents.trimRight().split...)

Comment: You can remove newlines at the end of the string first before the split `const lines1 = contents1.replace(/\r?\n$/g, '').split(/\r?\n/);` or filter the array from empty entries `contents1.split(/\r?\n/).filter(Boolean);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have an empty string at the last part of the string. To overcome this, you could match by non linefeed parts.

```js
const contents1 = 'line1\r\nline2\r\n';
const contents2 = 'line1\nline2\n';
const lines1 = contents1.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
const lines2 = contents2.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
console.log(lines1);
console.log(lines2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The empty string entry is fully expected because your sample strings represent files that end with an empty line. And that empty line is that empty string at the end.

So you regexp is correct. If you trim or remove the last value from the result, you basically change the the file representation - you'd remove the last empty line. A converter should not do that.